# MAKING A BOOTSTRAP 4 CAROUSEL SLIDER

Tags: asp.net, boot-strap

I tried to MANIPULATE an example BOOTSTRAP 4 CAROUSEL SLIDER  but I find  a problem when running my application in my site sharepoint 2013
here is my code

Previous
  
  
    
    Next

*Here's the result*
[image]

and here is the mistake in my console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are loading libraries in wrong order. jQuery must be loaded before bootstrap.js

## order of the libraries :

1 jquery.min.js

2 bootstrap.min.js

3 jquery.ui.js